# How do I make a list updates only on the second render?

Tags: reactjs

I have a state list that is called 'journal' and I want to add a state object that is called 'record' to the list after the user enters the data and set the state of the record.
Here's my states:

```
const [journal, setJournal] = useState([]);
const [record, setRecord] = useState({});
```

And here's the method that takes the data from user to set the record:

```
    function AddRecord(debitAccount, debitValue, creditAccount, creditValue, description){
    setRecord({date: new Date().getDate().toString(), debit: {[debitAccount]: debitValue},
    credit: {[creditAccount]: creditValue}, description, id: new Date().getTime().toString()});
}
```

I'm using a useEffect to update the journal every time the record changes like this:

```
    useEffect(()=>{
setJournal([...journal, record])
 }, [record])
```

But it adds an empty object at the beginning of the array.
Can someone please tell me how to fix this, I'm still trying to figure my way around states in react, and they're just getting complicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a misuse of `useEffect`. Effects should be used to react to, and tie together, things which happen outside the business logic of the component (i.e. prop changes, multiple concurrent fetch calls), or resubscribe listeners which are dependent on state values. Just move all the relevant code into `AddRecord`:

```
function AddRecord(debitAccount, debitValue, creditAccount, creditValue, description){
  const newRecord = {
    date: new Date().getDate().toString(), 
    debit: {
      [debitAccount]: debitValue
    },
    credit: {
      [creditAccount]: creditValue
    }, 
    description, 
    id: new Date().getTime().toString()
  };

  setRecord(newRecord);
  setJournal([...journal, newRecord]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

useEffect will be called on component initialization try to use some other way maybe useCallback function

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` runs on mount, and each time `record` changes, that's why it runs when record is empty. Just add a condition:

Also do not use `journal` directly, it's not guarantee that it has the expected value. Use set state callback instead:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (record && record.id) {
     setJournal(journals => ([...journals, record]))
  }  
}, [record])
```